# Обработчик событий

Tags: button, java, калькулятор

Делаю калькулятор, надо, чтобы по нажатию определенной кнопки выводилось в edittext определенное число. На курсах показывали такой способ реализации слушателя, НО помню только начало.

```
public void onClick (View v) {

Button b = (Button)v; (обрабатывает все кнопки)

//...здесь вроде был код...

chto_bilo = input.getText().toString(); chto_budet
= input.setText().toString(); rezultat = chto_bilo + chto_budet;

input.setText(rezultat);
```

**UPD**
Спасибо всем за помощь, простите за потрепанные нервы. Спросила у преподавателя, вот ответ.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);

    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);
    button4.setOnClickListener(this);
    button5.setOnClickListener(this);
    button6.setOnClickListener(this);
    button7.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

   Button b = (Button)v;

   String a = input.getText().toString();
   String c = b.getText().toString();
   String r = a + c;

   input.setText(r);
```

Comment: Вы бы лучше код не показывали, а просто вопрос написали. На это страшно смотреть

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, ваш комментарий очень помог. И да, я новичок.

Comment: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/16-urok-9-obrabotchiki-sobytij-na-primere-button.html Не пропускайте лекции

Comment: Спасибо за статью, но ничего нового я не узнала, мне нужен именно тот способ обработки события.

Comment: @Alina0118, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Это не учебное задание, просто увидела 4 способ обработки слушателя, сне нужно просто восстановить код.

Comment: и этот код в конце поста складывает числа ? ох

Comment: а что не так? все нормально работает, без всяких условий, код очень компактный.

Comment: у Вас при нажатии на любую из всех кнопок будет одно и тоже действие, при том конкатенация строк. Что-то Вас учат явно не тому.

Answer (score 3):

Если Вы действительно хотели бы знать, то сами нашли бы нужную информацию. Но все же я попробую ответить на Ваш вопрос.
Что такое слушатель? На английском это так и называется Listener. Это один из шаблонов проектирования, который впервые был описан в книге "Банды Четырех" или же GoF (Gang Of Four). В этой книге он называется Observer. Кстати, не всегда Listener и Observer обозначают один и тот же шаблон, но обычно это одно и то же.
В чем заключается суть? Представьте пример, у Вас есть подписка на журнал "Шаблоны проектирования". Вы оформили подписку на почте. Вы выступает в роли Observer по диаграмме. А оформляете подписку у `Subject` с помощью метода `registerObserver`, в нашем случае лучше `subscribe`.
Тем самым попадает в список подписчиков. Как только на почту привезут новую пачку журналов (произойдет требуемое событие), почтальон пройдет и разнесет всем журналы - метод `notify` на схеме. ТО есть Вы подписываетесь на интересующее Вас событие.

[image: Observer]

Теперь насчет Вашего примера. У Вас, по идее, весь Ваш класс главного `Activity` реализует интерфейс `OnClickListener`. ТО есть Ваше активити может обработать нажатия на клавиши, потому что реализует метод `onClick(View v)`.
В вашем случае Вы, скорее всего, делаете так:

```
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

То есть передаете управление по нажатию на кнопку Вашему активити.
А то, что Вы спрашиваете, скорее всего, надо сделать таким образом:

```
Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Обрабатываем нажатие на кнопку
    }
});
```

Тут Вы создаете анонимный класс, который реализует интерфейс `OnClickListener`. И сразу пишете, что Вам надо делать по нажатию на клавишу.
Про анонимные классы я рассказывать не буду, так как это довольно большая тема и не относиться напрямую к вопросу.
Вообще в андроиде у Вас есть множество возможностей задать обработчик кнопки. Это использовать все возможные варианты из Java (annonymous,implement interface..), а также задать прямо в xml файле с помощью

```
 android:onClick = "clickHandler"
```

В случае кнопки происходит то, что я описал про журнал. Вы даете кнопке знать, что Вы хотите узнать о том, когда кнопку будет нажата. Сам класс кнопки содержит внутри структуру для хранения заинтересованных слушателей, как только происходит событие, то кнопка вызывает все заинтересованных, с помощью вызова метода `onClick(View v)` у слушателей. 
Кстати, стоит заметить, что в Андроиде Вы можете задать только одного слушателя по нажатию на кнопку, а классический шаблон подразумевает возможность добавления нескольких слушателей, как в примере с журналами. Можете посмотреть Java Swing, там как раз можно добавлять несколько слушателей.

Думаю, что я достаточно подробно расписал, если у Вас будет желание разобраться, то найдете нужную информацию, а если лишь бы сдать, то ищите на других ресурсах помощи, но уже за деньги.

**EDIT**

Если взять Ваш пример, то, по описанному Вам заданию, Вам просто нужно по нажатию на кнопку установить в поле ввода значение.
То это очень просто, не понимаю, в чем проблемы.

Вот смотрите, только я не буду переменные называть, как у Вас, кнопки на клавиатуре отказались нажиматься. Вы, конечно, не обижайтесь, но старайтесь сразу писать переменные, чтобы было понятно, что они значат, Вам в будущем легче будет.

```
    EditText editTextFirstNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editfirst);
    EditText editTextSecondNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editsecond);
    EditText editTextResult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editresult);
    public void onClick (View v) {

 //   Button button = (Button)v; (обрабатывает все кнопки)

     switch(v.getGetId());
        {
          case R.id.addbuttonid:
          int firstNum = Integer.parseInt(editTextFirstNum.getText().toString());
          int secondNum =  Integer.parseInt(editTextSecondNum.getText().toString());
          int result = firstNum + secondNum;
          editTextResult.setText(String.valueOf(result)):
          break;
          case R.id.anotherbtnid:
          ........
       }
    }
```

В этом примере показана операция сложения. Берем два числа из двух полей и записываем результат в третье.
Если Вас опять же правильно понял. Вы ж поймите, это не я сам придумал, я, наверное, все возможные способы привел, которые можно использовать. Тем более зачем изобретать велосипед, все люди этим пользуются.
Или Вы хотите, чтобы Вам люди ответили посимвольно, что там на Ваших курсах написал преподаватель. Только если он так же, как у Вас, переменные называл, может, не стоит платить зря, при желании можно практически всему научиться из Интернета, благо, что материалов больше чем достаточно.

Учтите, что код выше не является образцом или хорошим кодом, он написан лишь для понимания. Так что в серьезном проекте код бы выглядел иначе (отловить NumberFormatException, название переменных...).

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ, но похоже меня не поняли.
1. Я еще пока не студентка, просто хочу начать программировать под Андроид.(вследствие посещаю курсы,на которых ДОМАШЕК НЕТ!). Для себя занимаюсь я.
2. Все ваши примеры и объяснения мне уже известны, т.к перебрала и изучила довольно много статей по данной теме.
3. МНЕ НУЖЕН ИМЕННО ТОТ СПОСОБ РЕАЛИЗАЦИИ СЛУШАТЕЛЯ.
Надеюсь меня услышали.

Comment: @Alina0118 
1)советую капс сильнее зажимать. так ведь лучше видно.
2)чего ты хочеш конкретно? чтобы тебе код восстановили ? и как ты это представляешь, если даже неизвестны имена полей.
3)код писать за тебя вряли ктото будет. Скорее помогут ошибку найти, а работу - нет.

Comment: свой пример приведите просто, как таким способ обработать несколько кнопок подряд.

Comment: Я вот не пойму, если Вы все то, что я описал, знаете, почему Вы сами не можете сделать, при понимании хотя бы того материала, что я описал, Вы сами можете полностью реализовывать этот шаблон проектирования. 
Вы объясните, что конкретно Вам нужно сделать? Реализовать свой механизм обработки событий? 
Возьмите реализуйте кастомную вьюху. Кстати, сам Button наследует TextView. Добавьте свой собственный механизм обработки событий. 
Если Вам просто надо установить в поле определенное число по нажатию на кнопку, то не понимаю, в чем проблема.
Посмотрите мой пост, я обновил с Вашим примером.

Answer (score 1):

Таким способом обработать несколько кнопок очень легко. B методе `public void onClick (View v)` у объекта `v` можно получить ID - [вот документация](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId%28%29). Этот метод вернет ID источника события. Для того чтобы это происходило, нужно предварительно зарегистрировать слушателя на том объекте, который нужно прослушивать методом [setOnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)). Далее когда произошло событие, получаем ID и пихаем его в switch (сравнивая с ID существующих кнопок, ИД которых можно получить из файла R.xml). Таким образом одним слушателем обрабатываем нажатия на множественные кнопки.

P.S. Беги проч со своих курсов.
P.S.S. Пора свой "бызнесс" открывать, для "обучения".

Comment: этот способ мне уже знаком, но все равно спасибо

Comment: Кстати, этот "код"

    chto_bilo = input.getText().toString(); chto_budet
    = input.setText().toString(); rezultat = chto_bilo + chto_budet;

не может работать по определению. Т.к. он производит конкатенацию строк, а не чисел.

Comment: насчет перемен, это сделали для "особо одаренных" в группе:D